# Im having a problem sending email on windows live mail / windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I keep getting this error message when I try and send mail, can anyone help please. cheers

The server does not support a SSL connection.

Subject 'Testing'
Server Error: 250
Server Response: 250 8BITMIME
Server: 'mail.btinternet.com'
Windows Live Mail Error ID: 0x800CCC7D
Protocol: SMTP
Port: 25
Secure(SSL): Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you manually changed the port to 25 but kept SSL on, Go to `Accounts` then go to the `Advanced` tab and under `Outgoing mail (SMTP):`, uncheck the following:

`This server requires a secure connection (SSL)`

[image]

Comment: That's WLM, not OE. you'll have to right click your account and select Properties: http://www.authsmtp.com/images/windows-live-mail-2009-1.jpg

Comment: @Molly you can do either, the accounts menu option is still there.